# Connect three monitors with one graphic card

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, clone, displayport, splitter

I want to connect my computer with three monitors (clone the third monitor). But my graphic card supports only two monitors. Is there nevertheless a solution to CLONE(NOT DUPLICATE) the third monitor? I used a Displayport-Splitter 1x2. But after connecting everything it was not possible to clone my third monitor.

Comment: Clone and duplicate mean the same thing in this context, do you mean to extend your desktop across all three monitors rather than have the same thing on particular screens? If that is not what you mean then please be clear about what screens need to show the same and which need to be different.

Comment: DisplayPort is designed to be split into up to 4 *independent* displays, so you need to double-check which type of DisplayPort "splitter" you're getting.

Comment: @mokubai I mean, my second monitor should have the same view as my third monitor.

Comment: I don't think this will work. I've never had a DP splitter so I'm not aware of how they work but AFAIK you can't put out to more displays from one GPU as it allows you to. Alternative: USB GPUs. Definitely sufficient for desktop work and they aren't that expensive either.